# Can two lights be switched between without an "ON-ON" switch?

Tags: circuit-design

[image]

The schematic above shows our problem. We need to be able to turn on light A when a switch connected to light A is closed and then turn on light B when the switch is open.

There are a few constraints:

- the lights must have a common ground
- they must have a common power source
- the switch can either connect A to the battery or be open. It cannot connect to B in it's open state
- no additional switches can be added, we want to be able to control it with just the single switch (they can be added if they don't have to be actuated by the user, we just basically want one user input)
- only "traditional" sorts of electronic components can be used such as wires, diodes, resistors, capacitors etc.

The blue area just signifies that it can be filled with whatever wiring is necessary to achieve this.

Is this setup possible to achieve?

This question has the practical application of being used as wiring for a go kart brake system. I've been trying for a while to look on the internet for answers but I don't think there's much hope.

Comment: Can you use a relay? Or a some transistors?  Also, what is the the voltage you're using, 12V?

Comment: Yes I could look into relays and transistors but is there a way to control them with only one voltage input? Yes the battery is 12v (high amperage due to it being a motorcycle battery)

Comment: What would you consider "non-traditional" sorts of components and why can't they be used?

Comment: state "A" diagram makes no sense .... is this a school assignment?

Comment: Non traditional just mainly refers to stuff like a microcontroller or specific use components. @jsotola sorry I know that state A makes no sense it's just supposed to be a representation of what I want the circuit to behave like, not a functioning schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple and obvious solution is to use an SPDT switch, but since you've ruled that out, a relay can do the job:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftmeAF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll have to look into relays a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want is relatively simple:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKxVRf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note: SW2 would be an ignition switch turning all the power off.

Comment: I see, so a mosfet would do the job. Thanks for the help. I'm marking the other person's answer as the answer just because it was posted sooner.